# Replace non-IPS screen with IPS one

Tags: display

Is it possible to replace a non-IPS led-backlit screen with an IPS one, on a laptop?

Assuming the connector, screen size and resolution are the same.

**Edit:**
Since you found the question too broad, although I find it specific and short, let me make it more specific for you guys.

I have an [Acer Aspire V3-371](http://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/model/NX.MPFEK.053) that has a Full HD 13.3' [Active Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active-matrix_liquid-crystal_display) [TFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film-transistor_liquid-crystal_display) Colour [LCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display). The screen has poor [viewing angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_angle) and below average brightness for outside use (around: [235.6](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Acer-Aspire-V3-371-Notebook-Review.135831.0.html) cd/m²). This is why I was thinking of replacing the panel only with a brighter IPS screen.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible and some resellers even offer options to do that before you buy the laptop. Search for your laptop model and panel model (latter would be more informative) to see what's available.